# Centering constraint in UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to vertically center a button within a UITableViewCell subclass using a constraint. My understanding is that I need to add a constraint in the updateConstraints method of the cell. Here's what I have:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    // Center the play/pause button vertically
    let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item:playPauseButton,
                                attribute:.CenterY,
                                relatedBy:.Equal,
                                   toItem:contentView,
                                attribute:.CenterY,
                               multiplier:1.0,
                                 constant:0.0)
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    playPauseButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addConstraint(centerY)
    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

But this isn't doing anything (the button appears at the top of the cell).

Comment: Try doing that in awakefromnib if you have an xib or  in initwithframe method

Comment: I tried it in awakefromnib, and got the same result, the button is still at the top of the cell.